# How can i replace default JSON.stringify variable K and A with my own variable

Tags: javascript, json

I want to my polygon points into the database through ajax. So i used like this

```
function StorePolygon(id, poly_points) {
   var html;
   // The values of id=1001 and poly_points=((47.53208121578362, 7.705052197034092),
   //   (47.53188401121172, 7.704971730763646),(47.53189169452062, 7.705076336915226))
   $.ajax({
     url: url_prefix + "SetPolygonInfo",
     data: ({
        'id': id,
        'polypoints': JSON.stringify(poly_points),
        'as_json': 1
    }),
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {

        html = result.html;

     },
     error: function(data, status, e) {
        alert(e);
     }
 });
 return html;
 }
```

the JSON.stringify(poly_points) produces like this

```
[{"k":47.53208121578362,"A":7.705052197034092},
 {"k":47.53188401121172,"A":7.704971730763646}, 
 {"k":47.53189169452062,"A":7.705076336915226}]
```

I want to use my own Variable instead of K and A.Can Somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just don't want to depend on JSON.stringify(poly_points) variables to store in the DB. So i did like this

```
function StorePolygon(id, poly_points) {
var html;
var olist = []
var obj = {}
/*
JSON.stringify(poly_points.map(function(point) {
    obj = {
        'x': point.k,
        'y': point.B
    }
    olist.push(obj)

}))*/

for(var i=0;i<poly_points.length;i++){
var xy = poly_points[i];
obj = {
        'x': xy.lat(),
        'y': xy.lng()
    }
    olist.push(obj)
 } 
 $.ajax({
    url: url_prefix + "SetPolygonInfo",
    data: ({
        'id': id,
        'poly_points': JSON.stringify(olist),
        'as_json': 1
    }),
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {

        html = result.html;

    },
    error: function(data, status, e) {
        alert(e);
    }
});
return html;

 }
```

It worked Fine. JSON.stringify(poly_points) sometimes gives k and A

```
 [{"k":47.53208121578362,"A":7.705052197034092},
  {"k":47.53188401121172,"A":7.704971730763646}, 
  {"k":47.53189169452062,"A":7.705076336915226}]
```

but some times it gives

```
 [{"k":47.53208121578362,"B":7.705052197034092},
  {"k":47.53188401121172,"B":7.704971730763646}, 
  {"k":47.53189169452062,"B":7.705076336915226}]
```

So I dont want my object/return list depends on the variables.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321609/how-can-i-replace-default-json-stringify-variable-k-and-a-with-my-own-variable/25321655#25321655) to create a new array of objects that have the keys you want to use and the JSON.stringify that array instead:

```
JSON.stringify( poly_points.map(function (point){
  return {
    custom_key_for_k : point.k,
    custum_key_for_A : point.A
  };
}) )
```

You'll need to [shim map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) to support Internet Explorer prior to version 9, or use an equivalent function from any Javascript library which includes it.

Comment: +1 Wow that is a legit use of map can't believe I never thought of that.

Comment: @@Paulpro: I first check the values of point.K using alert ,but its empty. May i know y?

Comment: @stackOverFlow I mistakenly used a capital `K` when it should've been lowercase. Use `point.k` instead.

Comment: @@Paulpro: Now I see the JSON.stringify variables are k and B(before it was A).Whats the reason of?

Comment: @stackOverFlow I don't think I understand what you are asking? Did you put `B` for the `custom_key_for_A`?

Comment: @@Paulpro: No, I mean alert(JSON.stringify(point)) shows me {"k":47.53184815575533,"B":7.705221176202031}. I Wonder where B comes from.

Comment: @stackOverFlow Oh, that means that poly_points contains that from wherever you are originally fetching it from.

Comment: @@Paulpro: I have one doubt. Why the JSON.stringify variables changes sometimes. alert(JSON.stringify(poly_point))before has variables k and A. But now it has k and B. Y is that so. Does google map do anything with this.

Comment: @stackOverFlow I don't think so. I believe a maps API points only have an `x` and a `y` property. Is there some other code acting on `poly_points` before you call `StorePolygon`?

Comment: @@Paulpro: I get the poly_points value from another function like this  var poly_points=overlay.getPath().getArray();

Comment: @@Paulpro: I dont want to depend on JSON.stringify(poly_points) variable. Is there any other to return the poly_points something like obj.x ={47.53208121578362,47.53188401121172,47.53189169452062} and obj.y={7.705052197034092},7.704971730763646,7.705076336915226}?